# How can i read a text file and diplay it in a netbeans JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextarea

I'm working in a Netbeans GUI project. All I want to do is to read a text file from a path and display it in a `JTextArea` using Netbeans. How can I achieve this?

Is there any simple way to do this just using the file path?

Lets say i want this be done after a button click..

Comment: Hi Jamaica... does your problem consist in reading a text file or in setting hte taext for a JTextArea? You should be more specific. Also what have you got so far (code)?

Comment: Read up [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) and JTextArea. You might want to share parts of your code to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Suppose i have a text in a folder with the name file.txt and some text in it. All i want to do is to diplay this text in a JTextArea.

Comment: I havent write any code yet. All i have done is some graphic parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- read Oracles tutorial about [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)
- use [JTextArea.read(Reader in, Object desc) throws IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 3):

See [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) for almost a 'one-line solution'.